# Streaming RTP with VLC-WinRT from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, libvlc

I am trying to stream audio file via RTP protocol from UWP application to RTP client. I'm using VLC-WinRT. I tried code below but after I run it there are no packets sent (checked with Wireshark).

```
Instance instance = new Instance(new List<string>
{
    "--sout=#rtp{dst=239.0.0.1,port=5004}",
    "--no-sout-all",
    "--sout-keep",
});

StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///NewFolder1/" + "uLaw 8kHz.wav"));

Media media = new Media(instance, file.Path, FromType.FromPath);

var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

log is below

```
main input debug:     `file:///C:/Users/.../bin/x86/Debug/AppX/NewFolder1/uLaw%208kHz.wav'     successfully opened
main input debug: Buffering 0%
main input debug: Buffering 16%
main generic debug: creating audio output
main input debug: Buffering 33%
main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any":     4 candidates
main audio output debug: no audio output modules matched
main audio output error: no suitable audio output module
main input debug: Buffering 50%
main input debug: Buffering 66%
main input debug: Buffering 83%
main input debug: Buffering 100%
main input debug: Stream buffering done (350 ms in 1 ms)
main decoder error: failed to create audio output
main generic debug: creating audio output
main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any":     4 candidates
main audio output debug: no audio output modules matched
main audio output error: no suitable audio output module
main decoder error: failed to create audio output
main generic debug: creating audio outputmain input debug: EOF reached
main input debug: waiting decoder fifos to empty    
main decoder debug: killing decoder fourcc `s16l'
main decoder debug: removing module "araw"
main demux debug: removing module "wav"
main stream debug: removing module "record"
main stream debug: removing module "cache_read"
main stream debug: removing module "access_winrt"
```

Does anyone have idea what could be problem?

Comment: Did you build libvlc correctly?

Comment: Maybe it requires transcoding.  The RTP output may not be able to directly handle a "wav" input.  There are transcode examples for vlc here that might be able to help: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#RTSP_live_streaming

Comment: @mtz I didn't build libvlc, I used this nugget package [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libVLCX)

Comment: Please use [`VLC.MediaElement`](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement) nuget package that is available in uwp.